# Counting total number of unique characters for Python string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement, split

[image]

For my question above, I'm terribly stuck. So far, the code I have come up with is:

```py
def count_bases():
    get_user_input()
    amountA=get_user_input.count('A')
    if amountA == 0:
        print("wrong")
    else:
        print ("right",amountA)

def get_user_input():
    one = input("Please enter DNA bases: ")
    two=list(one)
    print(two)
```

My line of thinking is that I first:
1. Ask user to enter the DNA bases (ATCG)
2. Change the user input into a list
3. Going back to the main (count_bases) function, I count the number of 'A', 'T', 'C', 'G'
4. Use 4 if-else statements for the four different bases.

So far, my code only works up to the output of the user's input into a list. After that, an error just pops up.
Appreciate it if someone can point the right path out to me!
Thanks.

Comment: What is this error? Also, why have you commented out the first `def`

Comment: File "XXX", line 98, in <module>
    count_bases()
  File "XXX", line 74, in count_bases
    amountA=get_user_input.count('A')
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'count'

Comment: It seems like you're misunderstanding the use of functions. Read up a bit here, https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp, you need to use a return statement and then save it to a variable if you want to use `.count('A')`

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this code. `get_user_input` is a function but doesn't return any value. You probably need to return `two` and assign it to a new name in `main`. Your misconception about how functions work... can you imagine a program with thousands of functions? How do you expect to be able to use the results of function calls? Or even calling a function twice?

Comment: I would appreciate more helpful suggestions, thanks! unfortunately since I'm a complete beginner in python, I simply cannot imagine a program with thousands of functions. @PeterWood

Comment: Read a tutorial on [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions). They are simpler than you imagine.

Comment: @JammyDodger thank you! I've taken a look at the website - however I'm still confused. If I change my print(two) to return(two), how do I rename it under a .count statement in my main function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Your function get_user_input() has no return value
2. get_user_input.count('A') contains a function call, it will not work without parenthesis. Correct: `get_user_input().count('A')`
3. As mentioned in the comments, get_user_input() should only be called once since the users input will be collected at each call via the `input()` function.

This should work:

```py
    def count_bases():
        char_list = get_user_input()
        for char in 'ATCG':
            char_count = char_list.count(char)
            if char_count < 1:
                print(char + " not found")
            else:
                print(char + " count: " + str(char_count))

    def get_user_input():
        one = input("Please enter DNA bases: ")
        two=list(one)
        return two
```

Comment: And that is their main problem, not understanding how to use the result from a function call by assigning it a name.

Comment: I now edited the answer and added a possible solution

Comment: @Boketto thank you! I've a better understanding of how functions are used now, especially when calling two..

Comment: print() function in python has `,` as a delimiter for multiple arguments. `+` creates new strings, which isn't a good practice. :)

Comment: Thanks @RahulSoni. I now prefer f-string syntax like `f"{char} count: {char_count}"` (not working for < python 3.6)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

```
from collections import Counter

def get_user_input():
    input_str = input("Please enter DNA bases: ")
    c = dict(Counter('ACCAGGA'))
    return c

def count_bases():
    counts = get_user_input()
    dna_base = list("ATCG")
    for base in dna_base:
        if base not in counts.keys():
            print(f"{base} not found")
        else:
            print(f"{base} count: {counts[base]}")
```

**output** when I call `count_bases()`

```
Please enter DNA bases: >? ACCAGGCA
A count: 3
T not found
C count: 2
G count: 2
```

Comment: How do I implement this into my two functions?

Comment: Thank you! I have a better understanding of the counter function now :)

Comment: @aislinx You're welcome. Please select/upvote if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

What if you make a temporary set, which by definition only contains unique items/characters?  I.e. in the lines of `unique_chars=set(input_string)`?

And to count everything use a zip with a comprehension? For instance: `nr_of_instances=zip(unique_chars, [input_string.count(x) for x in unique_chars])`

There are probably easier more elegant ways of doing this, but to use some of the built in functions... Not everyday I use zip, but here it might come in handy?

Comment: `set(input_string)` is enough.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'm just a sucker for comprehensions :-) I've edited my answer.

Comment: I was about to suggest using a set

Comment: He would need a counter

Comment: Thanks, I added one possible way of counting instances.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the mistakes which may invoke errors are as follows:

- You haven't returned the list of DNA string from `get_user_input()`
- Due to some misunderstanding, you have a text `get_user_input` in the function `count_bases()`, which is neither a function call or a variable name.

Following code is for your reference, which rectifies the mentioned mistakes:

```py
def count_bases():
    inp = get_user_input()
    amountA = inp.count('A')
    if amountA == 0:
        print("wrong")
    else:
        print ("right",amountA)

def get_user_input():
    one = input("Please enter DNA bases: ")
    two = list(one)
    print(two)
    return two
```

The above code will provide count of just one base i.e. 'A'. In order to avail count of all the bases, this may help:

```py
def count_bases():
    inp = list(input("Please enter DNA bases: "))
    for base in 'ATCG':
        count_base = inp.count(base)
        if count_base == 0:
            print("Not found.")
        else:
            print ("Count of ", base," is: ", count_base)
```

Comment: You don't explain what you have done to fix the code.

Comment: `get_user_input()` is invoked twice, if you ignore the *typos*. And if we don't explain the changes to fix the code, how will the author understand the mistakes conducted by him/her?

Comment: They don't invoke `get_user_input` twice. It's not a typo, its a (somewhat common) misunderstanding of how to access results of calling functions.

Answer (score -1):

```
def count_bases(val: str, character: str) -> int:
    # return the count of character in val
    if character in val:
        return val.count(character)
    else:
        return 0

def get_user_input() -> None:
    # get the input from the user
    value = input('Please enter DNA bases: ')
    # find the unique characters in the input
    characters = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
    # find the count
    for char in characters:
        count = count_bases(value, char)
        if count == 0:
            # do something
        else:
            # do something else
```