# How do I return a list with the number of times any element occurs given an element that exists in that list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

It's a bit confusing.
So suppose my list is ['AAA','AAB','AAC','BAA','BAB','BBA','BBB','BBC','BCC']

I want to create a function that takes input like  'AAA'.

I want an output that will give you the count of each element.
I expect matching values to add 1 to the counter and those that do not match add 0.

I've been stuck on this. Would a list even be capable of this?

**Edit:** A better explanation would be:
So basically, what I have is  a bunch of different string combinations. I have a separate list that contains a differing amount of those combinations. I want my output to be the different string combinations and a count of how many times it occurred in the other list.

Comment: `from collections import Counter`; `my_counts = Counter(['AAA','AAB','AAC','BAA','BAB','BBA','BBB','BBC','BCC'])`; `my_counts[input()]`

Comment: Can you clarify your question more? I interpret this question the same as the other answer but I feel like that is not what you are asking. Can you show us what code you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly do you mean:

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 10, 40, 10, 50, 20]

print("Total Number of Times 10 has repeated = ", a.count(10))
print("Total Number of Times 20 has repeated = ", a.count(20))
```

If you want to learn more try:
https://www.tutorialgateway.org/python-count-list-items/

Answer (score 2):

Based on the other answers interpretation of your question you can use a `Counter` from collections:

```
from collections import Counter

l = ['AAA','AAB','AAC','BAA','BAB','BBA','BBB','BBC','BCC']
c = Counter(l)
print(c['AAA']) # 1
```

Which is roughly equivalent to:

```
def counter(lst):
    d = {}
    for element in lst:
        if element not in d:
             d[element] = 0
        d[element] += 1
    return d
```

Comment: So basically, what I have is  a bunch of different string combinations. I have a separate list that may contains a differing amount of those combinations. I want my output to be the different string combinations and a count of how many times it occurred in the other list.

Comment: Please provide a more detailed example. Your explanation is still extremely vague. Add an example input and output to your question.

Comment: so for example what i have currently is a dictionary: all_mutations = {"CTA":0, "CTC":0, "CTG":0, "ACT":0, "ACG":0}.  The values are all set to 0. Now I have a list with some mutations like mutations = ["CTA","CTC", CTG"]. I want the resulting dictionary to have an updated count so all_mutations = {"CTA":1, "CTC":1, "CTG":1, "ACT":0, "ACG":0}. I'm not sure if I should loop through the dictionary and see if any element in 'mutations' exist in dictionary and if so add plus one

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use the same solution that I gave for this question: [Counting total number of unique characters for Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58302602/5390478)

The only difference is that you have a list instead of a string to begin with.